# chrome extensions: Which will be better, ajax or chrome.extension.sendRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Not just faster but better both in speed and using resources/memory.

I have an app where I put in suggestions as user types in an input-type-text. So, should I use ajax to communicate between two pages or chrome.extension.sendRequest?

**EDIT**

I have a packaged app, all the app info is stored in background.html's websql database. there is an input-type-text on index.html (which opens when someone clicks on app logo form new-tab page)

The input on the index.html fetches suggestions from the database of background.html as the user types in it. (just like google does when you start typing the query on google homepage) I can fetch suggestion data in two ways, using XmlHttpRequest and through chrome's message passing api. Since there will be a lot of requests to the background.html, i was wondering which method would be efficient..

The app in question: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fddboknafkepdchidokknkeidnaejnkh?hl=en-US

**EDIT 2**

The app is 100% offline. I am not connecting to any server or website. I am not loading any external script, not even jquery. All the app ever connects to is the files in it's own directory. background.html loads when pc starts and index.html loads when user clicks the app icon in new tab page. To see everything in action, you can install the app and see it for yourself.

**EDIT 3**

I am using the regular ajax to call index.html from background.html and it seems to work fine. By the way, both index.html and background.html are in 'html' directory.

```
function ajaxcall(url,callback) {
    var call = new XMLHttpRequest();
    call.onreadystatechange=function() {if(call.readyState==4) callback(call.responseText);}
    call.open("GET",url+'#'+Math.random(),true);
    call.send(null);
}

ajaxcall('/html/index.html', function(response) {console.log('foo')});
```

Comment: Can you show what you add in index.html to handle this XHR request? Anyway, I don't think it is a good idea to use this technique. I think `getBackgroundPage` imposes no extra penalty in terms of speed and resources, You don't create extra objects with it. You don't access the network. You only use objects that are already in the memory. You should definitely try that out.

Comment: nothing.. no code in index.html. i use hash (#) to send url variables and read them with js on index.html. and thanks for the idea, i have heard about getBackgroundPage and i have this last concern. Both the index.html and background.html (along with their own js files) are quiet heavy. will i be calling off the code that i dont need..? or what if the index.html is not open but background.html is? with chrome's message api its request just gets ignored.

Thanks alot for you time, i hope i make sense.. :)

Comment: Your backgroundpage will always be in memory so I don't think it will be extra load when you reference it in index.html. If index.html is not open then it can't call any code. If I share code between pages I sometimes do like the following example: ´var jQuery = backgroundPage.jQuery;´. But I'm not quiet sure whether this is good practice. I haven't had any issues with it though.

Comment: hmm backgroundpage it is then! thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [message passing API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) whenever you want to communicate between content scripts and your other pages. I don't see how you want to use ajax here.

If you're communicating between let's say your background page and the browseraction popup you could also use [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) which simply returns you the `window` object from the backgroundpage. Due to the restrictions imposed on content scripts you can't use this function in content scripts. This means you will always have to use message passing api for content scripts.

Don't be fooled by the asynchronous nature of these message passing functions. it's just a design consideration from the Chrome team to use asynchronous functions (with a callback) everywhere. It doesn't mean they take a lot of time to execute. Although I haven't bench-marked them, They seem to execute almost instantaneously.

**Edit**

I misinterpreted your question. I thought you were asking about how to communicate between the different pages in your extension/app. What you are really asking is how to communicate with a web server.

The [message passing API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) (`sendRequest`) only works for communication between different parts of your app. The reason why this API is in place is because different parts of your app run in different environments, these are called [isolated worlds](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment). These environments  are completely separated from each other to protect you from malicious code. The only pinhole through these different environments is this message passing API.

If you want to communicate with a web server ('pages' as you call them) you will need to use ajax. With ajax you will also notice the tight security model of Chrome. Under normal conditions a webpage is only permitted to make requests to the same site it originates from. This is called '[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)'. because your extension/app is not hosted (it is packaged) it has no rights to access a web server by default. You, as a developer, will have to request this right to the user. You can do this by filling in the [`permissions`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) property in the extension manifest. Whenever the user installs your app he has to [accept](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html) that you have the right to access a certain web server.

As I read your question I am assuming you are still not very familiar with Chrome extensions, apps, Ajax and policy in a browser. I encourage you to read further on these topics while you are developing your app so you can ensure the security of your users.

**Edit 2**

Ok, so you're communicating between two different parts of your app, the index.html and the background.html. For this you can use `getBackgroundPage` and directly call functions defined in your background page. What you do is the following: In your backgroundpage:

```
window.getSuggestions = function(query) {
  // search database for query

  return ['suggestion1', 'suggestion2'];
};
```

Then you can call the following function on your main page (index.html):

```
var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var mySuggestions = backgroundPage.getSuggestions('suggestion');
console.log(mySuggestions);
```

It's that simple. You don't need any ajax or `sendRequest` for this. No asynchronous code at all. You can just call a function in a synchronous fashion and this will be returned:

```
['suggestion1', 'suggestion2']
```

I didn't benchmark this and I haven't seen any data about it yet but I'm pretty sure this code is a lot faster than the message passing API or ajax. I didn't know you could use `XmlHttpRequest` within your extension but if it's possible I expect it to be the slowest way since you're actually making a network call in stead of calling to in-memory objects. If you want to be sure about the timings I suggest you to benchmark them yourself. You can easily do this with Chrome by using the following code:

```
console.time('someID');
// perform heavy operation(s) here.
console.timeEnd('someID');
```

The time to perform this operation will be printed to the console.

**Edit 3**

Now that I think about it, I'm not really sure how you would do ajax between two pages inside an extension. Don't you need a web server for this task? Can you give an example in your question of how you achieved this in your app?

Comment: but i am talking about the ajax requests that a packaged app can send to its pages. I for example load my settings page from the app's directory through ajax.. so i thought which one would be better.. to use ajax to load the page with suggestions or get suggestions via message passing api.. i am not using any content scripts/page action/browser action at all. is a packaged app.

Comment: ´sendRequest´ is not for ajax. It is for communication between the different parts of your extension/app. Use the XmlHttpRequest for ajax. I update my question with an explanation about the difference and the way to use ajax in an extension/app

Comment: oh my.. i think i am unable to explain my situation.. let me try this again.. please try to cooperate, i am new to asking in such forums.. :) i will edit the question. Thanks alot for your time :)

Comment: I think it's clear. Didn't know you could use XHR within an extension/app. I updated my answer with what I think is what you need. Unfortunately I don't have any data on what is the best in speed and resources but I'm pretty convinced the method I suggest is the best in both criteria. If you want to be sure you should benchmark it yourself. Please post results if you decide to do so.

Comment: Oh by the way: Chrome canary crashed on installing your extension. Probably a bug in the canary build. Wasn't able to install it on the beta either since it is only for Chrome version 13 or higher. What features of version 13 extension API are you using?

Comment: its the [file system api](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/).. and i have canary and it seems to be working fine.. on both dev and canary. however they maybe some glitch when installing the app.. but it seems to work fine once installed. thanks for the feedback. sorry but this field gets submitted on pressing enter and submits my incomplete comment.. :P

Comment: ugh sorry for the trouble i was having hard time figuring out how to add code block in comments. so i am editing my question again.. srry but i am new to stack overflow..